# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP __when i want click jump

Tags: java, spring, apache, jsp, web

> 2017-07-26 20:59:20,477 ERROR [500.jsp] - Unable to compile class for
>   JSP org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:672)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:856)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:841)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2442)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2431)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException  at
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.getJspAttribute(Validator.java:1385)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1262)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:876)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1538)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2429)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:895)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1538)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2429)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2435)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:474)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1841)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)

Comment: I can run normally my web project, but some will report the error page jump. I tried to clean up to reconstruct the whole project, but still the same error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To be able to help you, you should also post the code which cannot be compiled.

Comment: Posting just an exception is not helpful to anyone. You should need to be specific about your problem and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reminder. Now on one additional code. I want to know why cannot compile this file, it's just a case. Because the JSP file according to the unified template to write a lot, but only two of them can not be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved the problem, this is a bug tomcat itself. Tomcat in 8.0.9, 7.0.55 and 6.0.42 version fixes the bug